# PHP 5.6 parse error using Nginx and FastCGI

Tags: php, nginx, php-5.6

I am using NGINX and PHP 5.6 and cannot seem to debug this error after an upgrade. My error log reads:

> 2015/12/29 11:57:56 [error] 928#0: *20485 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /var/www/magento/htdocs/pub/become/wp-content/themes/become/index.php on line 81" while reading response header from upstream, client: 83.110.226.45, server: sss.uat.*..com, request: "GET /become/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/sss.uat.*..com.sock:", host: sss.uat.***..com"

And this is my PHP

```
<?
if($sss_article_featuretitle==""){?>
    <?php echo mb_strimwidth(the_title(), 0, 40, '...'); ?>
<?php } else { //line 81
    echo $sss_article_featuretitle;
}
?>
```

The PHP 5.6 docs and some searching does not say why this query is no obsolete.

Comment: can you post more of your php?  there must be something else happening..

Comment: You could change the if syntax to be like this `<?if($condition):?>`...`<?else:?>`...`<?endif;?>` read more here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: aww man, if I'm right I'll post as an answer so Andrii doesn't gank my hard earned internet points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all excess open/close tags:

```
<?php
if ($sss_article_featuretitle=="") {
    echo mb_strimwidth(the_title(), 0, 40, '...');
} else {
    echo $sss_article_featuretitle;
}
?>
```

**Update:**
Try to change it like this:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

```
<?php if ($sss_article_featuretitle==""): ?>
  <?php echo mb_strimwidth(the_title(), 0, 40, '...'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php  echo $sss_article_featuretitle; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also make sure you don't use short open tag `<?`, which is not a good practice and is probably disabled in PHP settings, so should be turned on by `short_open_tag` directive in your php.ini file.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: I don't have this option because other files that this programmer has built have large HTML gaps between conditionals.

Comment: The issue was due to short_open_tag, we swapped servers and the host has disabled them and now our entire application is not working on our UAT environment. Shame. I like short tags personally

Comment: I also like it, but it causes troubles sometimes, like in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have short_open_tags enabled. It looks like that first PHP part is `} else {`. I think that it was maybe removed in PHP 5.6 or at least deprecated.

Can you upload phpinfo somewhere?